# Append child before a particuler child in jqtree

Tags: jqtree

I am using jqTree in our project
http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/

I have tree structure like this

```
-A
 -B
 -C
  -C1
  -C2
 -D
```

I want to add new child E to A in 2nd position like this

```
-A
 -B
 -E
 -C
  -C1
  -C2
 -D
```

How can I do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **addNodeAfter** function.

See http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#functions-addnodeafter